# Gatsby Link JSX element type 'Link' does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

After updating to Gatsby 5 I got the following error at places where I use [Gatsby Link](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-link/)

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'gatsby'

const Comp = (slug: string, value: string) => {
    return <Link to={slug}>{value}</Link>
}

'Link' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its type 'typeof import("/Users/.../node_modules/gatsby/index")' is not a valid JSX element type.

export default Comp;
```

I can't find a way to get around this

Updated all related packages (Gatsby v5.12.4, React v18.2.0 and their typings).

I expect to be able to use this component without errors

Comment: change this `(slug: string, value: string)` to => `({slug: string, value: string})`